# CTE for building a result that has one record for every Category and each of its ancestor Category in a self referencing hierarchy of table?

Tags: sql-server-2008, common-table-expression, recursive-query

e.g. If I have a table like below:-

```
    create table Categories(CategoryId int primary key,
 ParentCategoryId int foreign key references Categories(CategoryId))
```

e.g If I have the following data in my table:-

```
CategoryID  ParentCategoryId
1           2
2           3
3           4
4           NULL

Result:     

CategoryId  ParentCategoryId
1           2
1           3
1           4
2           3
2           4
3           4
4           NULL
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You should reformulate your question outside the title, inside the body of the actual question, for better readability

Comment: Why is this tagged .NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE(CategoryID INT, ParentCategoryID INT);

INSERT @MyTable VALUES(1, 2);
INSERT @MyTable VALUES(2, 3);
INSERT @MyTable VALUES(3, 4);
INSERT @MyTable VALUES(4, NULL);

; WITH CTE(RootCategory,CategoryID,ParentCategoryID,depth) AS (
    SELECT      CategoryID,CategoryID,ParentCategoryID,1
    FROM        @MyTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT      CTE.RootCategory, t.CategoryID, t.ParentCategoryID,CTE.depth + 1
    FROM        CTE
    JOIN        @MyTable t  ON t.CategoryID = CTE.ParentCategoryID
)
SELECT      CategoryID = RootCategory
            , ParentCategoryID 
FROM CTE
WHERE       ParentCategoryID IS NOT NULL OR depth = 1
ORDER BY    RootCategory
```

Result:

```
CategoryID  ParentCategoryID
----------- ----------------
1           2
1           3
1           4
2           4
2           3
3           4
4           NULL
```